# Using WebClient to download a zip file who's name can change monthly

Tags: c#, webclient

I need to download a file from http://nppes.viva-it.com/NPI_Files.html, the problem is that every month the filename changes.  I was hoping to be able to use a wildcard in the filename, such as NPPES_Data_Dissemination_*.zip but that doesn't work with WebClient.  Are there any other ways to download this file programatically using c# without knowing the exact name of the file.  There will always be 1 and only .zip file on this webpage...the program just won't know exactly what that name is.  Any ideas would be appreciated!!

Thanks!

Comment: You can't request a resource to which you do not know the name. The server responds with the resource you have requested. You need to find the name.

Comment: The HTTP protocol does not support that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to request a resource whose name you don't know over HTTP.

Instead, make a WebRequest for http://nppes.viva-it.com/NPI_Files.html and parse it for the string you're interested in, then request that; alternatively, get the NPI folks to provide a consistent name for the file (since there's only one, perhaps it should be called _latest.zip or something?)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the HTML Agility Pack (on NuGet) to parse the HTML and find the `<a href="">`.

Comment: Like SLaks said, you should first scrape the page to get the file name and then make a second request to download the file.